# How can I tell if I am iterating through a collection before I attempt to modify the collection?

Tags: c#

I want to remove an item from a collection only if I am not currently iterating through it.

Is there a way to know that it is safe to remove an item from a collection without using exception handling as part of the logic?

Comment: Do you mean only if you're not iterating through it on another thread?  If so, use locking to allow only one thread at a time to access the collection.  If not, how could you possibly not know you were iterating through it?  There would be iteration code wrapped around your "remove" code...

Comment: Just use a Stack<T>, as you iterate, add things you want to remove to the stack.  Then when done iterating, just do a while(stack.Count > 0) and Stack.Pop and remove from the list.  As to your question there is no real way to know you are in iteration other than by the code editor itself at design time.

Answer (score 3):

Not for built-in collections.

Internally most collections have some sort of version information that allows corresponding iterators to  check if collection was modified, but there is no "list of iterators over this collection" you are looking for.

You can create your own collection type that gives you such information, but be very careful to handle multithreading cases (if needed) and figure out how you want to handle corner cases like "got iterator, change collection, start iteration" or "got iterator and never use it, collection blocked from changes".